# selenium - ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not visible

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill login form, but got exception - ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not visible :

I try to wait for full page load with time sleep, and also i see that element is visible.. but ElementNotVisibleException occurs.

Why this happen's and how to fix this?

Here is my python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Rumbler(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        caps["marionette"] = True
        caps["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox"
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://mail.rambler.ru/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_rumbler(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").send_keys("login")
        #login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
        #print login
        #login.
        #login.clear()
        #login.send_keys("pass")
        driver.find_element_by_id("form_password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("form_password").send_keys("pass")

        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.form-button.form-button_submit").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.uiButton.uiButtonNormal").click()


    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()




python rumbler.py 

======================================================================
ERROR: test_rumbler (__main__.Rumbler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rumbler.py", line 28, in test_rumbler
    driver.find_element_by_name("login").send_keys("marmanager")
  File "/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/engine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 321, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/engine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 456, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/engine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/engine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not visible
```

Comment: Interesting, cannot reproduce the problem. What happens if you would not set the `marionette` to `true` and use regular `Firefox` driver?

Comment: i'am at ubuntu 16.04 with firefox 47.0 old driver does not work

Comment: What if you would downgrade firefox to 46 and use regular driver? I just want to identify where exactly the problem is.

Comment: yes It work's on older version https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/:        binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/f46/firefox')
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)